# Copy NULL values present in csv file to postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have csv file (y.csv) in the folowing format:

```
 's', '1999-10-10', '1999-12-12'
 'b', '99-10-10 BC', '1-10-10 BC'
 'c', 'NULL', 'NULL'
```

I have a few NULL values (for date) in it which I have indicated through the string 'NULL'.

I am trying to copy the csv file into postgres. For doing so I have created a table:

```
create table r (id character varying(255), timebegin date, timeend date);
```

Now I am trying to copy the above .csv file into postgres using the command

```
copy r from '/home/y.csv' delimiter ',' csv;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: " 'NULL'"
CONTEXT:  COPY r, line 1, column timebegin: " 'NULL'"
```

On doing so I am getting an error with NULL. Can someone please help me figure out the error and correct it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Have you tried it?

```
 copy r from '/home/y.csv' delimiter ',' csv WITH NULL AS 'null';
```

Comment: I try but I receive this error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH NULL"`;

Comment: `copy r from '/home/y.csv' with delimiter as ',' NULL AS 'null' csv;`  I don't know if syntax changed in later version of pgsql, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: @monteirobrena, leave off the 'WITH'.  It will work without it.

Comment: I usually go with copy table from filename WITH (FORMAT CSV, NULL "NULL") and it works

Comment: For me, the syntax that I use, working on PG 9.3 and above, is
`copy r from '/home/y.csv' WITH (delimiter ',', FORMAT csv, NULL 'null)';`

Comment: To get `\copy` like behavior you can do `COPY table_name FROM STDIN DELIMITER E'\t' NULL AS 'NULL';` and send tsv data to stdin

Answer (score 9):

after giving the path of the file, we need to use 'With' before adding other paramters -

```
copy r from '/home/y.csv' with delimiter ','  NULL AS 'null' csv header;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you are inserting `NULL` as string. Remove the quotes around `NULL` and it should work.

Comment: This is not a solution. What if this was an automated process?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO : I know this may not be an ideal solution but as it was mentioned in the question as `I have a few NULL values (for date) in it which I have indicated through the string 'NULL'.` It is clear that the error was because of trying to insert a string in the date column.

Answer (score 1):

**1st**
Replace all NULL with ' ' (Space).

**Then**
COPY r FROM '/home/y.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' NULL as ' ' CSV;