# Handle error with COPY command when using PostgreSQL

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I have a Python script that is executing the following command to copy the content of a CSV file to a database:

```
copy_query = "COPY table_name FROM STDIN DELIMITER '%s' CSV HEADER QUOTE '\"';" % (self.delimiter)
```

`table_name` represents an already created table with specific types. The data in the CSV file doesn't  always match with the column type. For example, the CSV file could be like this:

```
"row1", 123, "2012-11-11"
"row2", 346, "2012-11-12"
"row3", \N,  "2012-11-12"
```

As you can see, column 2 should be of type `int`, but since the data on row 3 doesn't match with type `int`, the entire operation fails. Is there a way to maybe reject this row altogether? I'd prefer it to fill in with some default value of the appropriate type, but rejecting the row outright is fine too. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Currently (9.5 and older, at least) PostgreSQL offers no way to let you transform or filter rows in `COPY` like this. The usual solution is to import to a temporary/unlogged table with all `text` columns, then do an `insert into ... select ...` to transform it. See many existing related answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy NULL values present in csv file to postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034674/copy-null-values-present-in-csv-file-to-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with COPY command but you could modify the target table to accept NULL for these numeric fields.