# Postgres table import gives "Invalid input syntax for double precision"

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I exported a postgres table as CSV:

```
"id","notify_me","score","active","is_moderator","is_owner","is_creator","show_marks","course_id","user_id"
8,False,36,"A",False,True,True,True,2,8
29,False,0,"A",False,False,False,True,2,36
30,False,25,"A",False,False,False,True,2,37
33,False,2,"A",False,False,False,False,2,40
```

Then I tried to import it using pgadmin:

[image]

But I ended up getting following error:

[image]

I checked the values of Score column, but it doesnt contain value "A":

[image]

This is the existing data in the `coursehistory` table (for schema details):

[image]

Whats going wrong here?

**PS:**

Earlier there was `grade` column with all `NULL` values:

[image]

But it was giving me following error:

I got same error even using `\copy`

```
db=# \copy courseware_coursehistory FROM '/root/db_scripts/data/couse_cpp.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv)
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(2)
CONTEXT:  COPY courseware_coursehistory, line 1, column grade: "NULL"
```

I felt that import utility will respect the order of column in the header of the csv, especially when there is header switch in the UI. Seems that it doesnt and just decides whether to start from first row or second.

Comment: there's a lot of mismatch in headers: what you say is your CSV doesn't have `grade` header, the order of fields is all over the place in further screenshots. "Process Watcher - Import" screenshot specifically tries to insert `grade`, then `score` and fails on that.

Comment: There was indeed `grade` column as seen [here](https://postimg.cc/RWpmBmVL). But with it, import was giving me [this](https://postimg.cc/MvDx9RC4) error. So I removed grade column from CSV. I felt that the CSV headers will be respected by import tool. But it doesnt seem to be the case. How should I then import this CSV to face no issues?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying this CSV (also shown in postscript of original question; this also contains `grade` column and has no header row):

[image]

using `\copy` command in psql prompt.

Start psql prompt:

```
root@50ec9abb3214:~# psql -U user_role db_name
```

Copy from csv as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035071/13782227):

```
db_name=# \copy db_table FROM '/root/db_scripts/data/course_cpp2.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your content, with an "A" as the fourth value:

> 8,False,36,**"A"**,False,True,True,True,2,8

And the your table course_history, with the column "score" in fourth position, using a double precision.

The error message makes sense to me, an A is not a valid double precision.

Comment: so the csv headers are completely ignored while importing? Because, in CSV, the column headers and values seem in sync.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean, but in you copy command, the fourth column you mention, is also the "score" column. Please take a step back, make some coffee and read the error messages. When your content says "A", and your table expects  a double precision, you know that you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Order of columns in the kind of import you are doing is relevant. If you need a more flexible way to do imports of csv files, you could use a python script that in fact takes into account your header; and column order is not relevant as long as names, types and no nulls are correct (for existing tables).

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine=create_engine('postgresql://user:password@ip_host:5432/database_name')

data_df= pd.read_csv('course_cpp_courseid22.csv', sep=',', header=0)
data_df.to_sql('courseware_coursehistory', engine, schema='public', if_exists='append', index=False)
```